# Как с помощью .sort() отсортировать двумерный массив?

Tags: массивы, сортировка, c++

Как с помощью .sort() отсортировать двумерный массив?

Comment: как использовать "вообще" или как отсортировать двумерный массив?

Comment: и так и так)

Comment: А как вы себе представляете отсортированный двумерный массив?

Comment: А что значит сортировать двумерный массив?

Comment: Отсортировать по строкам или по столбцам? По возрастанию или по убыванию?

Comment: Есть вероятность, что ТС желает отсортировать каждый массив в массиве...

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас нативный массив типо int ** то его можно сортировать как одномерный.

```
int arr[10][10];
//какая-то инициализация
std::sort(arr,arr + 10*10,std::greater<int>());
```

Как-то так

Comment: Автор, конечно, так и не сказал, по каким критериям он хочет сортировать матрицу, но в Вашем случае всякая связь элементов со строками/столбцами исходного массива просто теряется.

Comment: Любая задача по сортировке 2d массива с учётом его размерности в итоге всегда сведётся к сортировке набора 1d массивов. Если это правило не выполняется, то как правило стоит задуматься о смене дизайна.

Comment: Но обычно переупорядочивают строки или столбцы, а не перемешивают содержимое матрицы.

Comment: Обычно странное слово в данном контексте

Answer (score 1):

```
bool compare(int* x, int* y) {
    return ( (x[0] < y[0]) || ((x[0] == y[0]) && (x[1] < y[1])) );
}
```

-

```
// Двумерный массив
int** array = ...
// Количество строк
int rows = ...
// Сортировка массива
std::sort(array, array + rows, &compare);
```

Comment: не взлетит. вы отсортируете элементы с первого по первый плюс количество строк массива.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужно, то, что на рисунке ниже, а также, нужен сам алгоритм сортировки (технология), то разбирайтесь с моим кодом.

[image]

Код сортировки методом "пузырька" - один из самых простых и самых несовершенных:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int a[20][20];
    int b[20][20];
    unsigned short n, m, i, j, k;

    do
    {
        cout << "2 <= N <= 2; 2 <= M <= 2" << endl;     
        cout << "N = ";
        cin >> n;

        cout << "M = ";
        cin >> m;
    }
    while (((n < 2) || (n > 20)) || ((m < 2) || (m > 20)));

    cout << endl << "Ishodnaya matricza:" << endl << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = (rand() % 100) - 50;
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
            cout << setw(4) << a[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    int tmp; // переменная для временного хранения числа
    cout << endl << "Sortirovka po strokam:" << endl << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) // мотаю цикл строк
        for (j = 0; j < m-1; j++) // мотаю цикл столбцов
            for (k = j; k < m; k++) // сортирующий цикл
                if (a[i][j] > a[i][k]) // условие на сортировку
                { // для сортировки по убыванию достаточно заменить ">" на "<"
                   tmp = a[i][j]; // сохраняю максимум из 2-ух чисел в переменную
                   a[i][j] = a[i][k]; // минимум из этих чисел "всплывает" вверх 
                   a[i][k] = tmp; // максимум отправляю вниз (на место минимума)
                } 

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << setw(4) << a[i][j];

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "Sortirovka po stolbczam:" << endl << endl;
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
            for (k = i; k < n; k++)
                if (b[i][j] > b[k][j])
                {
                   tmp = b[i][j];
                   b[i][j] = b[k][j];
                   b[k][j] = tmp;
                } 

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << setw(4) << b[i][j];

        cout << endl;
    } 


    cout << endl << "Davi na ENTER!!!";
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Как я уже выше объяснил, метод пузырька очень неэффективный, более совершенный алгоритм ниже (вариант для сортировки по строкам):

```
cout << endl << "Sortirovka po strokam:" << endl << endl;

int tmp; // временная переменная
unsigned short minind, // индекс минимального элемента
mm = m - 1; // для цикла прокрутки столбцов
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) // мотаю цикл строк
{
    for (j = 0; j < mm; j++) // мотаю цикл столбцов
    {
        minind = j; // предполагаемый индекс минимума
        for (k = j+1; k < m; k++) // сортирующий цикл
            if (a[i][minind] > a[i][k]) // условие для поиска индекса минимума
               minind = k;
        // меняю местами минимум с j-тым элементом
        tmp = a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = a[i][minind];
        a[i][minind] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Этот код можно оптимизировать, если в 2 раза сократить число проходов цикла прокрутки столбцов - если в сортирующем цикле искать и минимум, и максимум, а в этом цикле минимум отправлять в начало строки (или столбца), а максимум в конец. Для сортировки массивов существует полно алгоритмов, но, насколько мне известно, самые оптимальные алгоритмы оправдывают себя только при сортировке больших массивов.

З.Ы. Код компилировал в Dev-C++ Compiler.

Comment: Вроде бы вопрос был про `sort`...